# chatter publisher actions in touch

Tags: chatter, mobile, publisher

Are there plans to add the global or object-specific publisher actions in Touch or Chatter Mobile apps?

For example, if I get my desktop users used to creating records via chatter, are they going to be able to do that via the mobile interfaces, too?

Comment: Salesforce hasn't given us any clues, but I suspect that this will be the case in a future release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a video on YouTube showing [Publisher Actions in Chatter Mobile](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=InBSP74O2Ps).

[Chatter Mobile 4.0](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/salesforce-chatter/id404249815) is now available in the App Store and it includes the new publisher actions.

Answer (score 1):

I was sat in Keynote at the London Cloudforce event the other month and George Hue gave a very big hint about this appearing soon in the Chatter Mobile app. He pointed to the block of six buttons in the current UI, highlighting the missing 6th button as being left as space for MDP! Given this statement and the expected push for this feature in the coming months, I would be surprised if we didn't see it by Dreamforce 2013.

Comment: I think the name also gives a hint as to the future. MDP = Multi Dimensional Publisher. If you can only do it on desktop, then that isn't very multi, is it?

Comment: LOL, yes, good point! :)