# Unable to see custom global publisher action

Tags: chatter, mobile, publisher

I have published a global custom publisher action using VF page exactly as mentioned in http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=creating_vf_pages_for_custom_actions.htm&language=en_US

And, I have added the action to chatter layout. The action is appearing in salesforce website. But, I couldn't not find it in Chatter Mobile (iOS).

At the same time I could create and find "Create A Record" type Global action in mobile immediately.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Are you running v4.0 of the Salesforce Chatter app? According to the video linked in this answer it appears to be supported now? http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/12175/chatter-publisher-actions-in-touch

Comment: Yes. I am using the latest one. "Create A Record" type actions are supported. I am not sure weather they are supporting custom actions (VF page).

Comment: This feature and much more is available on Salesforce1

Answer (score 1):

Would marking your VF with "Available for Salesforce mobile apps" help?  Just guessing.

[image: mobile checkbox for VF]

Comment: No... I don't think this feature available in Chatter Mobile yet.